Angular material styles Dev Tools breaks
This is the second time I see this with 2 apps in one month, when using the lastest (v18) Angular Material components, once you open Dev Tools, the styles change/break. I can't pinpoint why it is happening, seems like a bug tbh.
Date picker before:

Date picker after:


do you open dev tools docked, so it changes the screen dimensions, or pop-out? have you saved a view setting, for example mobile, in dev tools (that would get applied automatically when F12)

Hi @CeeMcSharpface, thanks for your response. Your question about a view setting got me thinking, I had a styles.css override enabled. Removing it solved the issue. Thanks for the help.
